# Disable Angular AuthGuard and Interceptors Security in Application, Toggle Feature?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

We are using Angular 8 and something with our JWT Token is not working. Currently need to work on other items, what is the best way to disable AuthGuard, AuthService, and Http Intercept,  (Angular security) in the app?
Does Angular provide any toggle features?

```
// src/app/app.routes.ts
import { Routes, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { 
  AuthGuardService as AuthGuard 
} from './auth/auth-guard.service';
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { 
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: Comment them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular itself doesn't have feature toggles solution included for services, guards or interceptors. You can achieve it yourself, I'd recommend to go for a run time solution that would be able to turn features on/off any time (not only in build time).

You just need to skip the actual auth functionality when it is turned off.
Let's say you create config JSON that will be in either assets, LocalStorage or fetched from a server. It can look something like this `{"skipAuth": true}`, notice the `true === off` logic as it creates a nice scenario when all features not mentioned are on by default.

Wrap the features config in some service or put it to your app state/store.

With Interceptor you'll have to do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private toggles: FeatureTogglesService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (this.toggles.features.skipAuth) {
      return next.handle(req); // do what you need to do when skipping (use mock token / nothing / return original request)
    }

    // code that is executed when Auth is turned on
  }
}
```

With Guard you'll have to do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private toggles: FeatureTogglesService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    if (this.toggles.features.skipAuth) {
      return true; // let everyone access the route
    }

    // code that is executed when Auth is turned on
  }
}
```

And repeat for everything Auth related with the same `skipAuth` flag so nothing that needs to be skipped gets forgotten.